# React Native - reduce render times to optimize performance while using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

## Background

---

After releasing `React v16.8`, now we have hooks to use in React Native.
I am doing some simple tests to see the render times and the performance between
Hooked functional components and class components. Here is my sample:

**@Components/Button.js**

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const Button = memo(({ title, onPress }) => {
  console.log("Button render"); // check render times
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} disabled={disabled}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});

export default Button;
```

**@Contexts/User.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import User from '@Models/User';

export const UserContext = createContext({});
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let [ user, setUser ] = useState(null);

  const login = (loginUser) => {
    if (loginUser instanceof User) { setUser(loginUser); }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{value: user, login: login, logout: logout}}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function withUserContext(Component) {
  return function UserContextComponent(props) {
    return (
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {(contexts) => <Component {...props} {...contexts} />}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

## Cases

---

We have two cases below for constructing screen components:

**@Screens/Login.js**

## Case 1: Functional Component with Hooks

```
import React, { memo, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import Button from '@Components/Button';
import { UserContext } from '@Contexts/User';

const LoginScreen = memo(({ navigation }) => {
  const appUser = useContext(UserContext);
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false);

  const userLogin = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('blahblahblah');
    if (response.is_success) {
      appUser.login(user);
    } else {
      // fail on login, error handling
    }
  };

  const toggleFoo = () => {
    setFoo(!foo);
    console.log("current foo", foo);
  };

  console.log("render Login Screen"); // check render times
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={userLogin} title="Login" />
      <Button onPress={toggleFoo} title="Toggle Foo" />
    </View>
  );
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

## Case 2: Component wrapped with HOC

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import Button from '@Components/Button';
import { withUserContext } from '@Contexts/User';
import UserService from '@Services/User';

class LoginScreen extends Component {
  state = { foo: false };

  userLogin = async () => {
    let response = await UserService.login();
    if (response.is_success) {
      login(user);      // function from UserContext
    } else {
      // fail on login, error handling
    }
  };

  toggleFoo = () => {
    const { foo } = this.state;
    this.setState({ foo: !foo });
    console.log("current foo", foo);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render Login Screen"); // check render times
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Login Screen</Text>
        <Button onPress={userLogin} title="Login" />
        <Button onPress={toggleDisable} title="Toggle" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Results

---

Both cases have identical render times at the beginning:

```
render Login Screen
Button render
Button render
```

But while I press the "Toggle" button, the state changed and here is the result:

#### Case 1: Functional Component with Hooks

```
render Login Screen
Button render
Button render
```

#### Case 2: Component wrapped with HOC

```
render Login Screen
```

## Questions

---

Although the Button Component isn't a large bunch of codes, considering the re-render times between two cases, `Case 2` should have a better performance than `Case 1`. 
However, considering the code readability, I definitely love using hooks more than using HOC. (Especially the function: `appUser.login()` and `login()`)

So here's the question. Is there any solution that I can keep the benefits of both size, decreasing the re-render times while using the hooks? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that both button re-render even though you use `memo` in case of a functional component is because the function references are changed on each re-render as they are defined within the functional component.

Similar case will happen if you use `arrow functions` in render for a class component

In case of a class the function references don't change with the way you define them as functions are defined outside of your render method

To optimize on rerenders, you should make use of `useCallback` hook to memoize your function references

```
const LoginScreen = memo(({ navigation }) => {
  const appUser = useContext(UserContext);
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false);

  const userLogin = useCallback(async () => {
    let response = await fetch('blahblahblah');
    if (response.is_success) {
      appUser.login(user);
    } else {
      // fail on login, error handling
    }
  }, []); // Add dependency if need i.e when using value from closure

  const toggleFoo = useCallback(() => {
    setFoo(prevFoo => !prevFoo); // use functional state here
  }, []);

  console.log("render Login Screen"); // check render times
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={userLogin} title="Login" />
      <Button onPress={toggleFoo} title="Toggle Foo" />
    </View>
  );
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Also note that `React.memo` cannot prevent re-renders due to context value changes. Also note that while passing value to context provider you should make use of `useMemo` too

```
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let [ user, setUser ] = useState(null);

  const login = useCallback((loginUser) => {
    if (loginUser instanceof User) { setUser(loginUser); }
  }, []);

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setUser(null);
  }, []);

  const value = useMemo(() => ({
     value: user,
     login: login,
     logout: logout,
  }), [user, login, logout]); 
  /*
     Note that login and logout functions are implemented using `useCallback` and 
     are created on initial render only and hence adding them as dependency here 
     doesn't make a difference and will definitely not lead to new referecne for 
      value. Only `user` value change will create a new object reference
  */
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question, also for pointing out some other possible optimizations I can do. Appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in functional component whenever the component re-render, new `userLogin` created => `Button` component is re-render.

```
const userLogin = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("blahblahblah")
    if (response.is_success) {
      appUser.login(user)
    } else {
      // fail on login, error handling
    }
 }
```

You can use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to memoize `userLogin` function + wrap `Button` component with `React.memo` (as what you did) prevent unwanted re-render:

```
const userLogin = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("blahblahblah")
    if (response.is_success) {
      appUser.login(user)
    } else {
      // fail on login, error handling
    }
}, [])
```

The reason why it not happen in class component is when class component is re-rendered only `render` function is trigger (of course some other lifecycle function such as shoudlComponentUpdate, componentDidUpdate trigger too). ==> `userLogin` not change ==> `Button` component is not re-render.

This is [great article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) to have a look about `useCallback` + `memo`

Notice: When you use `Context`, `memo` can not prevent the component, which is a `Consumer`, re-render if values of Context Provider changed.
For example:
If you call `setUser` in `UserContext` => `UserContext` re-render => `value={{value: user, login: login, logout: logout}}` change => `LoginScreen` re-render. You cannot use `shouldComponentUpdate` (class compoenent) or `memo` (functional component) to prevent re-render, because it's not update via `props`, it's updated via value of Context Provide

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question. ;)